# UI Bootstrap - missing contains implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

How is it possible that jqLite doesn't provide the method "contains" on element ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)), angular bootstrap doesn't provide it neither ([source](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js)), angular bootstrap doesn't depend on jQuery ([package.json](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/package.json)), nevertheless angular bootstrap is using it ([line 2943](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js#L2943))? Where does it come from?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: This `contains()` method is not part of jQuery. It is part of the [DOM API](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_contains.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to explain:

`$element` is a `HTMLElement` browser html object which is *wrapped* in a JQuery/JQlite object.

When you call `$element[0]` you get first the *actual* `HTMLElement` that is wrapped (in this case the authors know that only one element is wrapped).

`HTMLElement` inherits from `Node`. The `Node` object has the `contains(...)` method.

Reference:

HTMLElement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement

Node: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node